# How can I set a UIView to hidden in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building my first app with Xamarin. I created a UIView called reord_overlay. I want to set it to hidden after ViewDidLoad:

```
record_overlay.Hidden = true;
```

What I get is an error about the

```
../VoYo/iOS/ViewController.designer.cs(27,27): Error CS0102: The type `VoYo.iOS.ViewController' already contains a definition for `recording' (CS0102) (VoYo.iOS)
```

How can I set the view to be hidden?

The error says it is in my ViewController.designer.cs file:

```
// WARNING
//
// This file has been generated automatically by Xamarin Studio from the outlets and
// actions declared in your storyboard file.
// Manual changes to this file will not be maintained.
//
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace VoYo.iOS
{
    [Register ("ViewController")]
    partial class ViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        UIKit.UIButton Button { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIView record_overlay { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIActivityIndicatorView recording { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIActivityIndicatorView recording { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextView Voice { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (record_overlay != null) {
                record_overlay.Dispose ();
                record_overlay = null;
            }
            if (recording != null) {
                recording.Dispose ();
                recording = null;
            }
            if (recording != null) {
                recording.Dispose ();
                recording = null;
            }
            if (Voice != null) {
                Voice.Dispose ();
                Voice = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My code**

```
using System;

using UIKit;

namespace VoYo.iOS
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        //int count = 1;

        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {       
        }


        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Code to start the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent
            #if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
            Xamarin.Calabash.Start ();
            #endif

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            Button.AccessibilityIdentifier = "myButton";
            string[] countries = {"Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"};
            record_overlay.Hidden = true;
            Button.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                //var title = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
                //Button.SetTitle (title, UIControlState.Normal);
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int length = countries.Length;
                int i = rnd.Next(0, length);
                Voice.Text = "You sound like someone from "+countries[i];
            };
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {       
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();        
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you're getting has nothing to do with "Hidden = true".  It sounds like you have a control declared twice, both in your code behind and in your UI (storyboard or xib).

Comment: Can you edit your question with more of your code?

Comment: I only get the error when I add the line. Otherwise the app runs on my iPhone. I think you may be right about this causing multiple declaration. I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for changing the hidden property.

Comment: please post **your** code, not the code the designer creates for you

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the 2 declared `UIActivityIndicatorView recording { get; set; }`
in `ViewController.designer.cs`

Be sure to double check of any outlet reference leftovers for recording UIActivityIndicatorView

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with `record_overlay.Hidden = true;` bug is not there.

Just open your XIB with Xcode Interface Builder, remove outlet references of `UIActivityIndicatorView recording`, open `ViewController.h` and delete property, something like this:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *recording;`

You might have 2 duplicated rows, just remove and add outlet again.